# Merging and analyzing usage statistics

Tags: google-analytics, matomo, usage-statistics, web-statistics

I'm working in a project in which we need to merge usage data from different sources, mainly from databases, to present them on a dashboard similar to google analytics, so it will be used to measure different conversion goals based on user activity. There will be multiple users with different data access restrictions.

We cannot use google analytics itself because there are usage statistics that come from other systems, not only web navigation. I check there is no way to upload our data to g-analytics so I've been searching for alternatives that let us upload our data and use the dashboard tools to analyze it.

Piwik seems to be a viable choice programming a pluging to collect data, anybody has use this tool to track custom data this way?, or any idea about other tools that provide a dashboard to analyze usage data?

Thank you

Comment: You can't upload data to GA - however you can import data from GA and other sources into a Google Doc and create a dashboard with Google Apps Script. Quite a bit of a learning curve, on the other hand you can focus on business logic and do not have to create the necessary infrastructure yourself.

Comment: We're looking for an open-source or vendor tool to reuse before start to think in develop all the infrastructure.

Comment: Goal tracking and custom variable tracking is available with PIWIK.

Comment: But, is possible to upload data from other systems?